# create multiple folders using folder/*/folder"

Tags: cmd.exe, wildcards, mkdir

I've been using this line to create multiple folders in different sub-folders using a wildcard:

```
FOR /d %A IN ("C:\users\me\desktop\test\*") do mkdir "%A\test3\"
```

My problem now is that I have to create multiple folders after the wildcard and only in an already existing folder called `test2`:

```
FOR /d %A IN ("C:\users\me\desktop\test\*\test2") do mkdir "%A\test3\"
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

[Wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) can only be used in the *last* element of a path, so you need to do this:

```cmd
for /D %A in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\test*") do if exist "%~A\test2\" mkdir "%~A\test2\test3"
```

Comment: You'll need an additional `if exist` otherwise mkdir will just create test2 everywhere.

Comment: You're right, @grawity, thanks for the hint! I updated my answer accordingly...